# Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) Magento2

Tags: magento2

I get error SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s).
My code is

```
orderId = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT sales_order.entity_id FROM sales_order INNER JOIN quote_id_mask ON sales_order.quote_id=quote_id_mask.quote_id AND quote_id_mask.masked_id='.$connection->quote($quoteId));
```